# How to prevent Google Sheets setting chart axis option "Treat Labels as Text" for imported xlsx?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I've imported an Excel spreadsheet containing a chart into Google Sheets.

Excel displays my axis like this:  [image]

After importing the xlsx into Google Sheets the Axis displays like this:

[image]

I can get Google Sheets to display the Axis labels the way I want by unselecting **"Treat Labels as Text"** in the Google Sheets chart options.

Is there a way that I can set something in the xlsx so that **"Treat Labels as Text"** is automatically deselected by Google Sheets after importing the spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi. I don't have an answer but I did notice this which explains _why_ the tickmarks are placed as they are. [How to increase precision of labels in Google Spreadsheets chart?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101537/196152)